# Why can't you delete your own recently closed posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, self-delete

I posted a [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/160773/is-the-27-i7-imac-a-good-buy-right-now-closed) that was closed as off-topic and decided rather than leave it there potentially causing any flame wars, it would be best to simply delete it.  Much to my surprise, I cannot delete the post because:

> To allow for possible reopening, you may delete in 2 days

Why should the OP have to wait 2 days to delete their own posts regardless of their closed/open status?

*Per the comment below with the FAQ, this is intended behavior, but I'd like to see the OP be able to delete their recently closed posts...*

Comment: It's either a feature-request if you're requesting that we have the functionality, or a support question if you're asking why the functionality exists in this fashion; it's not a bug as it is expected behavior according to the [deletion FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222). Your question seems to be support so I have tagged it as such.

Comment: @Grace Note - So clearly it's not a bug as they seem to have designed it that way...  This then is a feature request and the edits to this post were wrong...

Comment: @GraceNote I'd bet this was a bug that was retroactively labeled by-design. It seems more likely that they neglected to exclude one's own posts than that they intended to create a single 48-hour window within which a post's owner can't delete it (as rationalizable as that is). *[edit: Oh, this is just the most recently bumped of  dozens of posts about this; probably not the best place to make an argument.]*